# Nested directed subgraphs

Tags: graphviz

I'm trying to obtain nested subgraphs in graphviz.

Graphviz version is 2.38.0 (20140413.2041)

Here is the code:

```
digraph G {
        subgraph cluster_win {
                style=filled;
                color=lightgrey;
                label = "Windows"

                subgraph extra_enabled {
                    fillcolor = "#EDF1F2"; 
                    color = "#028d35";
                    label="Subdirectory extra included";

                    node [style=filled,color=white];
                    config_debug1 [label = "Configure Debug"];
                    config_release1 [label = "Configure Release"];
                    build_debug1 [label = "Build"];
                    build_release1 [label = "Build"];

                    config_debug1 -> build_debug1;
                    config_release1 -> build_release1;

                    shape=rect;
                    style=rounded; 
                }

                subgraph extra_disabled {
                    label = "Subdirectory extra excluded";

                    config_debug2 [label = "Configure Debug"];
                    config_release2 [label = "Configure Release"];
                    build_debug2 [label = "Build"];
                    build_release2 [label = "Build"];
                    config_debug2 -> build_debug2;
                    config_release2 -> build_release2;
                }

                checkout [style=filled, color=white];
                checkout -> extra_enabled;
                checkout -> extra_disabled;
        }

        start -> checkout;

        start [label="git push"; shape=Mdiamond];
}
```

And this is the result.
[image: no nested subgraphs]

Graphviz draws two ordinary nodes "extra_enabled" and "extra_disabled". However, I want them to be subgraphs, containing nodes "Configure Release", "Configure Debug", "Build" and another "Build".

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to do two things:

- Connect nodes only, you cannot connect to a cluster
- Cluster names need to be prefixed by `cluster_`

Applying this to your code

```
digraph G {
        subgraph cluster_win {
                style=filled;
                color=lightgrey;
                label = "Windows                  "

                subgraph cluster_extra_enabled {
                    fillcolor = "#EDF1F2"; 
                    color = "#028d35";
                    label="Subdirectory extra included";

                    node [style=filled,color=white];
                    config_debug1 [label = "Configure Debug"];
                    config_release1 [label = "Configure Release"];
                    build_debug1 [label = "Build"];
                    build_release1 [label = "Build"];

                    config_debug1 -> build_debug1;
                    config_release1 -> build_release1;

                    shape=rect;
                    style=rounded; 
                }

                subgraph cluster_extra_disabled {
                    label = "Subdirectory extra excluded";

                    config_debug2 [label = "Configure Debug"];
                    config_release2 [label = "Configure Release"];
                    build_debug2 [label = "Build"];
                    build_release2 [label = "Build"];
                    config_debug2 -> build_debug2;
                    config_release2 -> build_release2;
                }

                checkout [style=filled, color=white];
                checkout -> config_debug1;
                checkout -> config_release2;
        }

        start -> checkout;

        start [label="git push"; shape=Mdiamond];
}
```

I get

[image]

which is probably close to what you want. Note that I have added a few spaces to the label "Windows      " to get it out of the way of the arrow. You could also use `labeljust`. There are also ways to make the edge end at the boundary of the cluster, but that would have needed a lot more editing on my part which I was not sure you want it.

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to append to the answer that vaettchen added. While it is correct that you cannot directly connect edges to clusters, edges must travel between nodes, there is a way to do so visually with lhead and ltail.

You can do the following:

```
node1 -> node2 [lhead=cluster_name_1, ltail=cluster_name_2]
```

Which will cut the connectors off at the limit of the cluster to connect clusters, this is just visual and is logged as a node connection, but it is a nicer way to visually display connections between whole clusters.